# Driver/Library Solution for PostgreSQL in production

Tags: database, postgresql, erlang

I've been doing some analysis and tests to estimate an approximate server cost for a FreeBSD, Erlang Yaws stack and a distributed PostreSQL cluster.

What are some commonly used (not best since it depends on the use case) and actively developed database connection solutions for PostgreSQL in Erlang? I'd prefer the solutions to be peer reviewed and used by known Erlang endorser organizations.

Comment: Appreciated. Let me rephrase it more appropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Postgres interface is *really* simple and has been stable for quite a long time. Both Erlang bindings to Postgres that I've seen folks use haven't been updated for a few years, but are *very* simple to understand and work just fine.

- https://github.com/epgsql/epgsql
- https://github.com/noss/pgsql

The situation is not like psycopg2 in Python where the library itself has tons of features and requires regular maintenance (though some feature additions might be in order now, not because Postgres has changed but because Erlang has a few new tricks, like maps, now).

It should also possible to do the ODBC thing with Postgres, but I've never seen this done. Both of the above libraries connect over TCP.

Comment: Chicago Boss uses epgsql. I am using CB with Postgres for 2 years and I have never experienced any problems. Actually CB uses a fork https://github.com/mabrek/epgsql that made the calls asynchronous. It is more fresh, but still last commit is from 2013.

Comment: Actually ChicagoBoss uses fork https://github.com/epgsql/epgsql - it's main epgsql repo now.

Comment: @P_A Good to know! Updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I'm glad the async fork is mature. Thanks for the helpful comments and the answer. I'll close the topic soon.

Answer (score 1):

If I would start new project with psotgresql I would definitely take a look at https://github.com/semiocast/pgsql. At a first glance it is clear and simple (didn't used it so can not say anymore). As a second candidate I would take https://github.com/epgsql/epgsql, it is working horse proved by production usage.